# How to comment all the crontab entries and then uncomment same using a script

Tags: shell-script, cron

Just to be clear I want to comment crontab entries, not a basic file. Usually, I do it like

> crontab -e

```
30 * * * * /u01/app/abccompny/scripts/GenerateAWRReport.pl
01,31 * * * * /u01/app/abccompny/scripts/table_growth_monitor.sh
30 0,4,8,12 /u01/shivam/script/getMongoData.sh
```

and I add "#" in front of each line and just save it. Similarly after work is done I remove the "#".

```
#30 * * * * /u01/app/abccompny/scripts/GenerateAWRReport.pl
#01,31 * * * * /u01/app/abccompny/scripts/table_growth_monitor.sh
#30 0,4,8,12 /u01/shivam/script/getMongoData.sh
```

Is there an efficient way to do this using the script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Export your current crontab into a file, delete the crontab, then use the previously created file.

```
$ crontab -l > cron_content
$ crontab -r
$ <this is where you do your stuff>
$ crontab cron_content
```

Answer (score 1):

### We will copy cron to some other file, make changes and again apply the cron.

Copy your cron to some file,

```
crontabl -l > filename
```

Now `filename` has your cron, you can apply your cron using

```
crontab filename
```

---

Comments starts with #, so we will add and remove # from start of the line.

To add and remove comments you can use `sed`

Remove comments (#)

```
sed -i -e 's/^# //g' filename
```

Add comments (#)

```
sed -i -e 's/^/# /g' filename
```

---

Apply cron using

```
crontab filename
```

Check you cron

```
crontab -l
```

---

```
Happy Scripting
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below script to add or remove comments from crontab.

```
#!/bin/bash

# you must have permission to read the crontab

if [[ $1 == "-add" ]]; then
        crontab -l > /tmp/cron_export
        awk '$0="#"$0' /tmp/cron_export > /tmp/cron_comment
        crontab -r
        crontab cron_comment
elif [[ $1 == "-remove" ]]; then
        crontab -l > /tmp/cron_export
        awk '{ print substr($0,2) }' /tmp/cron_export > /tmp/cront_uncomment
        crontab -r
        crontab cron_uncomment
else    
        echo "no option was selected. Please use -add to add comments or -remove to remove comments"
fi

# Remove all the create files for the operations

for f in /tmp/cron*; do
    [ -e "$f" ] && rm cron* || echo "No files to remove were found"
    break
done
```

The usage of the script should be:

to add the comments

```
./youscriptname.sh -add
```

to remove the comments

```
./youscriptname.sh -remove
```

Answer (score 0):

Old post, but i think there is a much faster and easier solution :

On Linux, everything is a file. Crontab stores crons of each user in /var/spool/cron/

- On Ubuntu 20.04 : **/var/spool/cron/crontabs/<user>**
- On RHEL7 : **/var/spool/cron/<user>**

So you can just :

```
# comment
sed -i 's/^/#/' /var/spool/cron/<user>

# uncomment
sed -i 's/^#//' /var/spool/cron/<user>
```

Comment: This won't work reliably